# Find a cell value based on data in two columns of a table

Tags: excel, search, find, vlookup

Using and Excel formula, I would like to complete last three columns of table A below based on data in table B.
If any row of a particular ID in table B contain "Yes" in a year, then put "Yes" in table A on the col for same year. For example, ID=11 has "Yes" in one row in col=2015, in three rows in col=2016, and in no rows in col=2017. So put "Yes" in 2015 and 2016 columns in table A where ID=11

Table A

| ID | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 |  |  |  |
| 13 |  |  |  |
| 15 |  |  |  |

Table B

| ID | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 |  | yes |  |
| 11 |  | yes |  |
| 11 | Yes | yes |  |
| 13 | yes |  |  |
| 13 | yes | yes |  |
| 13 |  |  |  |
| 13 |  | yes |  |
| 15 |  |  | Yes |
| 15 | yes |  |  |
| 15 | yes | yes |  |
| 15 | yes | yes |  |

I tried,

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$2:$D$12,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$2:$D$12,3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$2:$D$12,4,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SUMPRODUCT()` with `IF()` function.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($H$2:$J$12="Yes")*($G$2:$G$12=$A2)*($H$1:$J$1=B$1))>0,"Yes","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` looks only for first value so in your data it will often be empty.
You can use `COUNTIFS`.

Formula in `G2` (and dragged to `I4`):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$F2,B:B,"yes")>0,"yes","")
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use VLOOKUP then it will require following approach.

[image]

Formula in highlighted cell which can be copied down and across(may need **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** in versions other than O365)

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2&"yes",$G$2:$G$12&H$2:H$12,1,0)),"","Yes")`

Answer (score 0):

Here,  an array version that spill all the result at once including header. In cell `F1` put the following formula:

```
=LET(id, A2:A12, data, B2:D12, ux, UNIQUE(id), yr, B1:D1,
 out, IF(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(N(id = TOROW(ux))), N(data="yes")) > 0, "yes", ""),
 VSTACK(HSTACK("", yr), HSTACK(ux, out))
)
```

`LET` is used for easy reading and composition, here the formula without using it:

```
=VSTACK(HSTACK("", B1:D1), HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A12), IF(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(N(A2:A12 
  = TOROW(UNIQUE(A2:A12)))), N(B2:D12="yes")) > 0, "yes", "")))
```

[image: excel output]

It uses `MMULT` to do the counts by **ID** and year (`out`), the rest is just to accommodate the output via `VSTACK/HSTACK`.